# Missing items on page

Tags: php, jquery, front-end

I'm missing items on my web page and I think it is due to some jQuery problems. But I'm not sure and I am unable to find the bug.

On [this site](http://theretailer.getbowtied.com/demo/pages/homepage-v2/), on the upper-right corner there is a shopping bag 'widget', and on [my site](http://bikepologear.eu) there is none but the white space indicates that it's trying to be there.

Now I made a gist of the differences of both sites (https://gist.github.com/mvaneijgen/d5784918e202ac19070f/revisions), but still cant find a bug maybe a more experienced WordPress developer sees it in a second.

I have tried disabling all the plugins, flushing the cache and ask for theme support on [GetBowTiedSupport - Ticksy](http://getbowtiedsupport.ticksy.com), but there's no response from the developer so I hope to fix it through this channel.

Comment: Look at your browser's error console, you have a bunch of 404 errors.

Comment: I only see warnings no errors

Comment: strange, first time I visited all the woocommerce js files 404'ed, but that's not happening anymore.

Comment: Your site seems to work now (widget in place and everything) so I assume the issue got resolved? You could post an answer if there is generic solution to the issue, otherwise we can close this so it doesn't haunt site as unanswered. :)

Comment: it was because of the theme was dump. i had installed WooCommerce already but it didnt understand that because the theme also wants to install WooCommerco. So i had to deinstall WooCommerce and let the theme install a really old version of WooCommerce and then upgrade to the current version of WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was because of the theme was dump. i had installed WooCommerce already but it didnt understand that because the theme also wants to install WooCommerco. So i had to deinstall WooCommerce and let the theme install a really old version of WooCommerce and then upgrade to the current version of WooCommerce.